# connecting a web service to wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

I have installed a wso2 identity server on my computer and now I am looking to have it act as an pdp and pep for my application which will be a website or database server.  I already know how to create policies, the problem is that i can not seem to find a tutorial for how to connect a service to the identity server.  what i want is for a tutorial to start off with the simple basic things and then I will be able to move on from there.  thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use Identity Server as PDP.  your application which is running on tomcat uses this PDP for authorization queries.  Therefore you want to create PEP component with your application.  PEP can do a web service call to WSO2IS PDP. Actually use can use the same PEP client source that is described in the above blog post.  You can easily integrate it with  your web app. However there is a sample web app that act as a PEP. Please refer the sample from [here](http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/03/06/xacml-sample-for-health-care/).  Also source code of this web app can be found at [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml-samples/medi.com/webapp/medi_com_webapp/). If you just go through source code, you could find how it has been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can find SOAP based PEP client for accessing WSO2 Identity Server's PDP from [here](http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/06/14/pep-client-for-wso2is-pdp/). Also If you want more details on PDP PED communication related to WSO2 Identity Server,  please find from [here](http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/06/13/pdp-pep-communication-wso2is/).

Comment: thank you for your reply dragon jake, the blog was useful in explaining the relation between the pep and the pdp but it did not show how the one connects to the other.  what was and still looking for is a way to have identity server act as a xacml engine to the application i have on my tomcat server, thank you for your effort